# Looped raster extractions from a SpatialPointsDataFrame; each row needs to extract from a corresponding raster indicated in a column

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration, raster, spatial

I am attempting to make a loop that extracts values from NDVI rasters for multiple shapefiles. The shapefiles are animal GPS locations that include a date and a time. The shapefiles include random locations that have been generated from the population's range and I am therefore assigning each random location that didn't have a date, a date from one of the GPS locations in a 5:1 ratio. I have a function that finds the closest date to the date for each GPS location or random point and stores it in the dataframe as "x$NDVIfile" **The code all up to this point but I think the problem is here specifically:**

```
for(j in length(nrow(x))){
    a <- raster(paste0("E:/RSF_GIS/HabitatVariables/NDVI/",
                       x$NDVIfile[j], ".tif"))          
    x$ndvi[j] <- raster::extract(a, x[j,])               # extract each row based on the closest NDVI file
  }
```

I want to extract from each row in my data the raster from the directory that corresponds to "x$NDVIfile[j]". My current outcome looks like this. All the extracted NDVI values are the same for each dataframe and I have the suspicion that the first raster referenced is the only raster being extracted from for each dataframe :

[dataframe x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yItuy.png)

Here is the entire code :

```
RSF_dir <- list.files("E:/RSF_GIS/RSF_files",
                      pattern = "*.shp",
                      full.names = TRUE)

ndvi_dir = list.files("E:/RSF_GIS/HabitatVariables/NDVI",
                      pattern = "*.tif",
                      full.names = FALSE)
ndvi_dir.df <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(ndvi_dir))
ndvi_dir.df <- as.Date(ndvi_dir.df)
ndvi_dir.df <- as.data.frame(ndvi_dir.df)

for (i in 1:length(RSF_dir)) {
  x <- rgdal::readOGR(RSF_dir[i])
  x <- as.data.frame(x)
  nona <- x$Acqst_T[!is.na(x$Acqst_T)]                 # make a list of non- NA values
  nona <- rep.int(nona, times = 6)                     # have the list repeat itself 6 times (5:1 = random_location:GPS_fix)
  x$Acqst_T <- dplyr::coalesce(x$Acqst_T, nona)        # and assign to NAs
  x$date <- as.Date(x$Acqst_T, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
  min_distances <- as.numeric(x$date)- matrix(rep(as.numeric(ndvi_dir.df$ndvi_dir),nrow(x)),ncol=length(ndvi_dir.df$ndvi_dir),byrow=T)
  min_distances <- as.data.frame(t(min_distances))
  closest <- sapply(min_distances,function(o) {        # function to find the closest NDVI date for each GPS fix
    w <- which(o==min(o[o>0]));                        # (MOD09Q1 collects imagery every 8 days)
    ifelse(length(w)==0,NA,w) 
  })
  x$NDVIfile <- as.Date(ndvi_dir.df$ndvi_dir[closest])
  x <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(data.frame(x$coords.x1, x$coords.x2), x, proj4string=veg_INREV@proj4string)
  for(j in length(nrow(x))){
    a <- raster(paste0("E:/RSF_GIS/HabitatVariables/NDVI/",
                       x$NDVIfile[j], ".tif"))          
    x$ndvi[j] <- raster::extract(a, x[j,])               # extract each row based on the closest NDVI file
  }
  writeOGR(obj= x, dsn="E:/RSF_GIS/RSF_files/trial", 
           layer=(paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(RSF_dir[i])))), driver="ESRI Shapefile", overwrite_layer = TRUE)
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don’t use images of code or data as they cannot be used without a lot of unnecessary effort. Questions should be reproducible. Check out stack overflow guidance [mre] and [ask]. Include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as `df <- data.frame(…)` where … are your variables and values or use `dput(head(df))`.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, the solution was simply a change in code indicating the iterations of the loop:

```
for(j in length(nrow(x))){
...
}
```

should have been instead

```
for(j in 1:nrow(x)){
...
}
```